# ROV-E compact configuration

Tags: mars, rovers

Assuming that ROV-E could be employed in a real space mission, which would be the best configuration to store it in a larger spacecraft or linked to a larger spacecraft? Is it possible to modify the position of the wheels achieving a more compact configuration?  I'm thinking to a mission concept similar to ExoMars (with ROV-E replacing Schiaparelli), but with lower mass and dimension. Which are the minimum dimension of ROV-E in a compact configuration during the Mars Orbit waiting for the right landing site?

Thank you for the help

Comment: For everyone wondering what ROV-E is: https://mars.nasa.gov/ask-nasa-mars/

Answer (score 1):

> ROV-E is mad mostly with off-the-shelf parts. For example, ROV-E is riding on remote-control truck wheels. Its two 'brains' are easy-to-program Arduino and Raspberry pi computers. A lot of parts were made using a 3D printer.
> <sub>(from [AskNasa](https://mars.nasa.gov/ask-nasa-mars/))</sub>

Obviously, ROV-E is not built for a space mission. On the AskNasa site, they show a video of ROV-E in an inside test environment with sand and stones (similar to mars), however, I believe it would hardly endure a day in a real desert, not to speak of a flight to mars or a landing...

If, however, NASA decided to launch a bunch of (more shielded / enduring) little ROV-E builds, they would likely be stacked in a way that is impossible to achieve with their current hardware.

ROV-E is built as a small, detail-reduced, cheap version of Curiosity / Perseverance (which share many features). If you have a look at the Perseverance rover, you can see how its legs and wheels can be organized in a more compact way...

[image]

You would also have to implement that for ROV-Es in before transporting them to mars.